# Update query multiple rows

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans

How to update "sisastock" on "tbpembelian" while user input data.

Example: user inputs data 120. Then "sisastock" update 0 and next row update 80

This my table rows :

[image]

Update: input data user 120 will insert into "stockJual" in "tbPenjualan"
then update on "tbPembelian"

input 120 then update:

1. Row 1: column "stockkeluar" = 100, "sisastock" = 0
2. Row 2: column "stockkeluar" = 20, "sisastock" = 80
   [tbpenjualan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1eG6.png)

Sorry about my English.

Comment: Could you put more details like what insert query you are writing while user is trying to insert 120 and what exactly is 120 in this case

Comment: @Eshu : i update my question. Sorry about my english

Comment: It's unclear what the logic is here. My guess is that the table tbPembelian is feeding the table tbPenjualan for idprd and reducing the values sisastock in idbell order to the value of a user input amount. Is that correct?

Comment: @P.Salmon yes. that is simple code if my user want it, but my user don't want to input stock many times in one product.. hehe

Comment: You could improve the question by adding the logic behind what you want to do together with sample data,expected outputs and table definitions as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably better doing this in your java code but you can do this in mysql using a procedure containing a cursor. For example

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T,T1;

CREATE TABLE T(ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,IDPRD VARCHAR(10), INSTOCK INT);
CREATE TABLE T1(ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,IDPRD VARCHAR(10), INSTOCK INT);

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS P;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE P(INPRD VARCHAR(10),INAMT INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE CONT INT DEFAULT 1;
declare finished int default 0;
declare vid int;
declare vidprd varchar(10);
declare vinstock int;
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR select id,idprd,instock from t where instock > 0 order by id;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

SELECT  CASE WHEN SUM(INSTOCK) < INAMT THEN 0 ELSE 1 END INTO CONT FROM T WHERE IDPRD = INPRD GROUP BY IDPRD;

if cont = 1 then
    start transaction;
    insert into t1(idprd,instock) values(inprd,inamt);
    open cur;
    fetch cur into vid,vidprd,vinstock;
    curloop: loop
        if finished = 1 or inamt = 0 then
            leave curloop;
        end if;
        if vinstock >= inamt then
            update t 
                set instock = instock - inamt
                where id = vid and idprd = vidprd;
            set inamt = 0;
         else
            update t
                set instock = 0
                where id = vid and idprd = vidprd;
            set inamt = inamt - vinstock;
        fetch cur into vid,vidprd,vinstock;
       end if;
    end loop curloop;

    commit;

end if;

END $$
DELIMITER :


truncate table t;
INSERT INTO T(IDPRD,INSTOCK) VALUES ('A1',100),('A1',100);

truncate table t1;
CALL P('A1',120);

select 't', t.* from t
union all
select 't1',t1.* from t1;

+----+----+-------+---------+
| t  | ID | IDPRD | INSTOCK |
+----+----+-------+---------+
| t  |  1 | A1    |       0 |
| t  |  2 | A1    |      80 |
| t1 |  1 | A1    |       0 |
+----+----+-------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```